# Add bottom border to specific number of columns in a row if criteria is met

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a column with groups of values 1, 2, 3, etc... and adjacent columns with additional details. I am trying to write a macro that will use the first column to determine if the value in a cell less than the one beneath it and, if so, add a bottom border to that cell and the next 6 cells in the same row.

For example, if D2 contained "2" and D3 contained "3", then D2,E2,F2,G2,H2,I2,J2 would all receive a bottom border.

I can underline D2 but I can't figure out how to get it to underline the next 6 columns as well.

Current Code:

```
'line divider between wire groups
    For i = 2 To ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If ws.Cells(i, 4) < ws.Cells(i + 1, 4) Then
            With ws.Rows(i, 4)(i, 5)(i, 6)(i, 7).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
                .ColorIndex = 1
            End With
        End If
    Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use VBA for this, it's a simple Conditional Format.

Select the range `D2:J2` and go to Conditional Formatting --> New Rule

Select "Use a formula to determine ..." and enter this formula:

```
=$D2=$D3-1
```

Then, go to "Format" and add a bottom border.

Comment: Thanks... I'd gone down a deep, dark VBA rabbit hole that I forgot I could solve it with standard Excel!

Comment: The serenity prayer for Excel:
Lord grant me the VBA skills to automate the things I cannot easily change; the knowledge to leverage fully off the inbuilt features that I can; and the wisdom to know the difference.